# Flow of control C++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{    
    char a[101];
    cout << "str a:";
    gets(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here why `gets(a);` is executing before `cout<<"str a:";`?

The compiler used: digital mars and GNN_gcc.

Comment: Do note the `gets` is not part of C++ anymore.

Comment: See the "as if rule" in C++. The cout and gets statements are not inter-dependant so no order is specified.

Comment: @doug Nope. These are executed in strongly sequential order. The problem is something completely different.

Comment: Yep, my error. Duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffers of `gets()` and `cout` are different. Since nothing is forcing `cout` to flush the buffer, the contents stays in the buffer when the execution reaches the `gets()` function. To force the outcome to match your expectation and execution order:

- Option 1: Use `cout << "str a:" << endl;` to force flushing the buffer content. You can also use `flush` if you don't really need a newline.
- Option 2: Use reader/writer functions that are using the same buffer and/or aware of each other. For example, read your input using `cin >> a;`, or `getline` reading from `cin`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: According the [reference docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) you simply can force synchronization of these. Also has nothing to do with the actual _buffers_ used in these functions.

Answer (score 8):

> Here why `gets(a);` is executing before `cout<<"str a:";`?

`gets()` isn't actually executed before `cout<<"str a:";`, you just missed to `flush()` the output stream to force printing on the screen:

```
cout<<"str a:" << flush;
```

should fix that.

As mentioned in [@Slava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965261/1413395) the streamed output is buffered and normally synchronized with `std::cin`.

The output is only really put at the device, as soon the buffer is full, or being forced using the [**`flush()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) function.

Since `gets()` is a (meanwhile deprecated) C-function, automatic synchronization isn't guaranteed, unless you call

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio();
```

once in your `main()` function (see the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) please).

---

A side note:

Instead of `gets()`, which is deprecated with the c++14 standard, you should rather use

```
std::string a; // Much more convenient than char a[100];
std::getline(std::cin,a);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here why gets(a); is executing before cout<<"str a:";?

It is not. You may think that because `cout` output is buffered and you do not flush it before calling `gets()`. `std::cout` is aware of `std::cin` and would flush before you get input from there. If you use C calls to input you either need to flush `std::cout` manually, or call [`sync_with_stdio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)